# Constructing a pseudo-Anosov homeomorphism

Tags: riemann-surfaces, low-dimensional-topology, foliations, teichmueller-theory

Let S be a genus 2 closed surface. Consider the two non-separating red curves (say $\alpha$ & $\beta$) in the picture. I want to construct a pseudo-Anosov homeomorphism $\phi: S \rightarrow S$ with stable foliation $(\mathcal{F}^{s},\mu^{s})$ such that $i(\mathcal{F}^{s},\mu^{s};\alpha)=i(\mathcal{F}^{s},\mu^{s};\beta)$. By Penner's construction of pseudo-Anosov maps, one can construct a pseudo-Anosov map using Dehn multi-twist along two multicurves that are in general position and fill the surface S. In this case, one can see that the stable foliation is supported by a train track symmetric with respect to $\pi$ rotation. But how can one ensure that the intersection number of such a foliation with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the same? And if not, how can one construct such a pseudo-Anosov map with the given constraint? Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: My suggestion is to use a different (and simpler) construction, namely, start with an affine Anosov diffeomorphism of $T^2$ and lift it to a 2-fold ramified covering. Try it. You will be a PA map which commutes with an involution which swaps $\alpha, \beta$.